# What are the composed function components called?

Tags: terminology

The answer might be so trivial; nonetheless, I was wondering in the function composition such as:

$k = f \circ g \circ s$,

k is called the composed functions. What is the terminology to refer to f, g, and s?

Comment: The components?

Comment: "Component functions"?  I'm not sure I've ever heard a term for those.

Comment: What I want to know is where the sequence k, f, g, s came from.

Comment: I would call them "composands", but I've never seen any widely used term for them.